# Why can't I connect to my localhost django dev server?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm creating a django app and in the process of setting up my local test environment. I can successfully get `manage.py runserver` working but pointing my browser to any variation of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, `http://0.0.0.0:8000/`, or `http://localhost:8000/` returns a "This site can’t be reached" error.

Simultaneously, django will throw a 301 error:

```
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[11/Jul/2017 23:35:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

I've successfully deployed the app to Heroku (all URLs work there), but I can't get it running on my local machine. I've also tried `heroku local`'s included dev server to the same effect.

For reference my django urls.py file looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from recs.views import Request1, Check1, index

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^analyze1/', Request1),
    url(r'^analyze1/status/', Check1),
]
```

Any help appreciated!

Edit:
Posting Settings.py

```
import os
import recs.environment_vars as e_v

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'KEY HIDDEN'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'recs',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'sslify.middleware.SSLifyMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'recs.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['recs/templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'recs.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, './static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Logs
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': ('Application Log: ' + '[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s [%(process)d] ' +
                       'pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s ' +
                       'funcname=%(funcName)s %(message)s'),
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'clothing_recommendation.clothing_recommendation': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        }
    }
}

import urlparse
# Celery + Redis - For long-lived asynchronous tasks (e.g. email parsing)
# Redis
redis_url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'))
CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": "{0}:{1}".format(redis_url.hostname, redis_url.port),
         "OPTIONS": {
             "PASSWORD": redis_url.password,
             "DB": 0,
         }
    }
}

# Celery
#CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60
BROKER_URL=os.environ['REDIS_URL']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=os.environ['REDIS_URL']
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 300
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 2
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'confirm_publish': True} # Hack to prevent failed 'success' of tasks, per MT's experience with RabbitMQ - probably doesnt work with Redis? But worth trying
```

Comment: just try python manage.py runserver and go to 127.0.0.1:8000 and see what you get and if the error staty post your settings file please

Comment: Above is when I try that. In Chrome all I get is a "This site can't be reached" error. Same in Safari. In the command line, I get the `[11/Jul/2017 23:35:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0` error.

Comment: please post your settings file

Comment: Added settings.py

Comment: you dont have a database right?

Comment: You're using sslify which would raise a 301 to https://127.0.0.1:8000. That could probably be the problem.

Comment: @Exprator - have a database. Deleted that section given username and password settings.

Comment: @ShobhitSharma - that did the trick for /admin ! 127.0.0.1:8000 is still not resolving to the index however...

Comment: ok so the problem is because of the https, thus getting redirected, as localhost is working on http, try to comment out this line and check SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https') and also comment out the sslify from middleware as said by  @ShobhitSharma

Comment: Amazing. Thank you both! Exprator and ShobhitSharma

Comment: @Exprator, as we can see that, you solved the issue. Why don't you post it in the answer section? And Roy can mark it correct answer. This question will not come as unanswered. BTW karma point for all of you.

Answer (score 1):

The OP posted the solution in the original question' comments but he/she seem to have forgotten to post it as an aswer. So here it is:

> Ok so the problem is because of the https, thus getting redirected, as
>   localhost is working on http, try to comment out this line and check
>   SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https') and also
>   comment out the sslify from middleware as said by @ShobhitSharma

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I accidentally put a `while` loop in `views.py`.It ran forever.So django couldn't serve the requests.