# localhost:8000 not working but 127.0.0.1:8000 is django

Tags: django, localhost

I'm not sure when it actually happened but I have a django project and when I run my server my app no longer works with `localhost` and instead works with `127.0.0.1`. I had changed my django version to 3.0 to use `drf-extensions`. I am not sure if when I changed to version 3.0 this occurred but it definitely happened somewhere around this point. Either when I used `drf-extensions` or when I switched my django version from 3.1 to 3.0. Everything was working fine before that

To my understanding they're the same but I'm not sure as to why it is not working. My main issue is not that I can't still work from my `127.0.0.1:8000` but that when I try to run my react server that is running on `localhost:3000` my backend gives me this error when trying to do an axios request

```
Exception Value: Incorrect padding
```

I changed the proxy in package.json to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000` but still no luck in getting axios to work and still end up with the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I connect to my localhost django dev server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45050668/why-cant-i-connect-to-my-localhost-django-dev-server)

Comment: I'm not sure if it does. As a solution for now I am actually able to serve my react and with axios working when i click on `on your network http://10.0.0.78:3000` this actually works fine. I start my react app doing `yarn start` and with my django server running and all works well, but I don't understand this. FYI I get to click on that network because when I run `yarn start` it shows up on the console as an option.